# Sum and difference of two numbers using 2Pointers through a single function

Tags: c

Main function should have a function call like adddiff(&p,&q) ... Function definition be like void adddiff(*a,*b) it should perform both addition and subtraction ,it should not return values and should not use print statement in adddiff method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both arguments are passed by reference, so you can use them to "return" the results to the main function.
Remember to save their values locally before overriding them, though!

```
void adddiff(int* a, int* b) {
    int orig_a = *a;
    int orig_b = *b;
    *a = orig_a + orig_b;
    *b = orig_a - orig_b;
}
```